# External SQLite File content accessing error

Tags: android, sqlite

I've the following code, it gives a run time error as below. Why?

```
try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}catch(SQLiteException e){}
```

Runtime Error:

```
:sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: android_metadata  
 :SELECT locale FROM android_metadata failed  
 :Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database  
 :android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
```

Comment: One solution can be, use openOrCreateDatabase instead of openDatabase. This will create the database if its not available.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure the table name `android_metadata` is there, with a column name `locale`, you could insert en_US as value for `locale`.

Or rather execute this sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US');
```

Edit: If you call openDatabase() with SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS flag, you would not need to have this table, else you will need to have this table around.

See [setLocale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLocale%28java.util.Locale%29).

Comment: no.. why that column is needed? in my app i am accessing a remote .sqlite file and displaying it. it doesn't contain any such file.. is that is compulsory for android?

Comment: After some googling, I could not find an answer to that as well, maybe you could post that as another question :)

Answer (score 8):

When open read only db and its not already created, use NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS.

```
try{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
    mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY+ SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
}catch(SQLiteException e){}
```

android_metadata table will be created if you open the database with write permissions.

Comment: the "+" in the flags addition is correct? probably should be an OR "|" isn't it?

Comment: its the pipe symbol, bitwise or |

Answer (score 5):

call openDatabase() with SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS flag,this is what i did when i met the problem last time...